# API that provides list of available indoor map

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-indoor-maps

I am working on indoor map in google map in which I want to show list of available indoor maps in particular country.

So, is there any API that provides list of available indoor maps with details in JSON format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Answer is : **NO**

Since I've worked on this, I can tell you that the concept of indoor mapping is still in infancy. Even Google's indoor mapping has bugs in it [As of the moment I am writing this]. ie when you try to navigate indoor, the direction is plotted from the nearest outside roads.

However, if your requirement is to build an indoor mapping application, Google has an option to upload floor plans inside their maps, however those are again subject to Google's procedures [[here]](https://maps.google.com/floorplans/uploadcontactme?hl=en).